# How to implement chrominance filtering in opencv?

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

I am new to Opencv. What I am trying to do is measure liquid level using single digital camera. After searching a lot I got one research paper having the algorithm and steps at the below link.

http://personnel.sju.edu.tw/改善師資研究成果/98年度/著作/22.pdf

But this algorithm having a step where I need to apply chrominance filtering on captured image. Opncv doesn't come with such inbuilt functionality. So how can I implement chrominance filtering, is there any way to to do this. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, any idea what is chrominance filtering?

Comment: You can know about chrominance filter on following address http://www.dvc.uk.com/acatalog/edius_colour.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to access the link yo provided, but I guess what you want to to is to segment your image based on the color (chroma). In order to do that, you have to first convert your BGR image (RGB but with the red and blue channels swapped, which is the natural ordering for OpenCV) to a chrominance-based space. You can do this using the function `cv::cvtColor()`with an argument such as `CV_BGR2YUV` or `CV_BGR2YCrCb`.

See the full doc of the conversion function [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

After that, you can split the channels of your images with `cv::split()`e.g. :

```
cv::Mat yuvImage;
std::vector<cv::Mat> yuvChannels;
cv::split(yuvImage, yuvChannels);
```

Then work on the image of the resulting vector that contains your channel of interest.

Comment: Just copy and paste the link in your address bar(mozilla) with chines alphabets then it will works.